# Attempted import error: 'ImageList' is not exported from '@material-ui/core'

Tags: reactjs, npm, installation, material-ui

Hello i'm working on a react app and i'm trying to import ImageList from @material-ui i use `"import { ImageList } from '@material-ui/core';  but it gives me error while compiling , i 've installed` npm install @material-ui/core`
Here's the dependencies i have
"@material-ui/core": "^4.11.4",
"react": "^17.0.2",
"react-dom": "^17.0.2"

Answer (score 0):

The ImageList component is only available in material-ui v5 (currently in alpha).

`npm install @material-ui/core` install the last stable version (v4.11.1)

For the alpha version you should use the following command `install @material-ui/core@next @emotion/react @emotion/styled` as described in the official documentation at https://next.material-ui.com/

Answer (score 0):

make sure you are using material ui 5. In material ui 4 you have to use GridList instead of ImageList